# Sharing Color Converter on MvvmCross for multiple platform (mvvmcross v3)

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

The problem answered on this Q&A is how we can show a color on our UI project using mvvmcross, when we have a ViewModel with for example an Enumeration Property, without the need to have a Color property, and without having a ValueConverter for each platform.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose you have a view model like this

```cs
public enum MyEnum
{
   Value1,
   Value2
}
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
   public MyEnum MyEnumProp { get... set...}
}
```

Supposing you want to show a Azure Color for Value1 and Black for Value2, you could implement this converter on you Core project.

```cs
public class MyEnumToColorConverter: MvxValueConverter<MyEnum, object>
{
    protected override object Convert (Multiplier value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        MvxColor mvxColor = null;
        switch (value) {
        case MyEnum.Value1:
            mvxColor = new MvxColor(240,255,255);
            break;
        case MyEnum.Value2:
            mvxColor = new MvxColor(0,0,0);
            break;
        default:
            mvxColor = new MvxColor(0,0,0);
            break;
        }

        var nativeColorConv = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNativeColor>();

        return nativeColorConv.ToNative (mvxColor);
    }
}
```

The trick is to call `Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNativeColor>()`. On your UI project if you have loaded the right Color plugin you will automatically get the right Color implementation for your platform.

Remember to add this line to your Setup.cs (not required if you add the color plugin Nuget package which automatically adds it to the Bootstrap folder).

```cs
Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Color.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
```